# "Feedback needed on proposed site" email contains email addresses

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, email

I recently received an email from Area51 pointing to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65439/should-developer-testing-be-folded-into-a-more-general-programmers-site) question about merging a few sites together.

I'm not sure whether the email was auto-generated, or done by a real human, but in the `to` field was listed the email addresses of all of the users who had (I assume) shown an interest by following the proposal.

If the email is auto-generated, I would class this as a bug that needs fixing as I don't really want my email address scattering to all of the other users who follow the group. If the email was sent by a human, someone needs to be educated as to why this is not a great approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this was entirely my fault.  Normally we send emails through code, which sends them all individually, but since this was (probably) a one-time email it was easier to just send it directly through the mail client.  I was in a hurry, and put the emails in the To field instead of the BCC field.  As far as I know, this is the only time this has happened, and it won't happen again.

Comment: EXTRA BEATINGS ARE IN ORDER! :)